# How to use target="_blank" in IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, target

I want to use the target blank in Explorer, but I'm not sure.
Please tell me how to fix it.

Comment: Please provide more details, i.e. your code that does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to open a link in a new window or tab? You can use `target="_blank"` according to [this article](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp).

I made a sample according to your comments in the answer. You can input website values into the textbox and it can open it in a new tab in IE:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" class="pdf-file-url" />
    <a href="#" class="btnZoom" target="_blank">link</a>
    <script>
        $('.btnZoom').on("click", function () { $('.btnZoom').attr("href", $(".pdf-file-url").val()); });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

what version of internet explorer are you using?

for me I used IE11, it is working fine in this version.

if it is not working then can use this JavaScript code as well, and call this to your anchor tag.

```
window.open('http://www.google.com','_blank')
```

Comment: I want to allocate href dynamically. I want to assign the variable of the url part of the window.open. How can I do this?  ex) <a href="window.open(url, '_blank')" >link</a>

Comment: Originally, it was used like this. $('.btnZoom').attr("href", $(".pdf-file-url").val());

Comment: $('.btnZoom').on("click", function() {
                   window.open( $(".pdf-file-url").val(),"_blank");
  }); << It is not working normally.

Comment: function openTab()
        {
            var data = document.getElementById('txtUrl');
            var url = data.value;
            window.open(url,'_blank');
        }

Comment: here is the JSfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/e3z6tqfL/ 

Note: one more thing which you have to do is enable active-X control. if you want to use this. that you can do in internet options> security tab. Without that this will not work in IE.